# How can i add a weight correctly in a classification algorithm created by me of handwritten sign?

Tags: classification, image-processing

I have 150 images of handwritten signs (like cross, star, circle, tridents), i extracted from them the number of branched point, ent-point and "close" a s feaetures (Having said that features are not enough): if they are a close figure like a circle or an open figure like a cross.

**Classification**:

```
Cross:   1 branched point and 4 end point, close = 0
Circle:  0 branched point and 0 end point, close = 1
Star:  5 branched point and 0 end point, close = 1   
Trident: 1 branched point and 4 end point, close = 0
...
```

I have 8 categories of images and for everyone i choose a range of branched points and a range of end points for classifying them in a certain category. So a star could be have not only 5 branched point and 0 end point like above, but a range of 3-8 branched point and a range of 0,4 end point.

For classifying any new image empirically, i decided that:

position: [cross, trident, unknown ...]

with close = 0 (open figure):

```
with branched point 0  [0,0,100...]
with branched point 1  [100,0,0...]
with branched point 2  [50,50,0...]
...
with branched point 4  [0,0,100,...]   
...
```

position: [circle, star, unknown ...]
with close = 1 (close figure):

```
with branched point 0  [100, 0, 0...]
with branched point 1  [0,0, 100...]
...
with branched point 4  [0,50, 50...] #a star with non precise feature extraction
with branched point 5  [0,100, 0...]
with branched point 6  [0,50, 50...] #a star with non precise feature extraction
```

position: [cross, trident, unknown ...]

with close = 0 (open figure):

```
with end point 0 [0,0,0,...]
with end point 1 [0,0,100,...]
with end point 2 [0,0,100,...]
with end point 3 [33,33,33...]
with end point 4 [5050,0,...]
with end point 5 [33,33,33,...]
```

position [circle, star,unknown,... ]

with close = 1 (close figure):

```
with end point 0 [50,50 ,0...]
with end point 1 [0,50,50...]
with end point 2 [0,50,50...]
...
```

**After that, i chose to give a weight.**
For doing that, i calculate the range of every category (for star: (1) branched point: 6-4 = 2, (2) end point 1-0 = 1.

if the figure have perfectly the right feature (star case:  0 end points; i give the maximum weight (30%). If it has 1 end point 15% . If it has 2 end points 0% weight.

I add the proper weight to [0,50,0,50,...] and subtract to the others for having always a 100% total.

At the end i add Branched points probabilities and end points propabilities and divided for 2.

```
(Bpoint prob + Epoint prob ) / 2 for every
```

Example: i get an image with 4 branched point and 1 end point, and it is a close figure:

the weight for a star with 1 end point is of 15% so:
the weight for a star with 1 branched point is of 20% so:

```
 branched point: [0,50,50...] -->    [0,65,35]
 end point:      [0,50,50...] -->    [0,70,30]
```

calculation:
    [0,65,35] +  [0,70,30] / 2 = [0, 67,5, 47,5]

so i have got a probability of 67,5% to be a star and a probability of  47,5% to be unknown. 0 % for other categories.

Unfortunately, in many cases i have negative percentages, or percentage over 100, how can i fix this?

Comment: It sounds like your weighting scheme was somewhat arbitrary: that would make it difficult for anyone to assess your procedure objectively. Have you done any testing of the accuracy of your classifier?

Comment: No, but I have a hunch that it is incorrect! How can i verify it? How can i change it?

Comment: well, i have 60% circa of correct result